# Facing error to upload projects on github. How to solve this issue?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push my project form local to remote. But while push it up then en error message shows. 
The message was "Failed to push some refs to 'http://github.com/--------'"
How can I solve this issue?

here is the screenshot of the console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwHZe.jpg)

Comment: Did you read the `hint:` lines?

Comment: Please read the whole error message, it even includes hints about how to fix the "problem". Did you notice that your "add origin" command above also gave an error? Could this be related? Did you want to change remote repository but this failed? Please examine the screenshot you posted and update your question with what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

before that you have fatal error. Do this. and try again.

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:ppreyer/WebPages.git
```